# In R, categorize time series data based on regex

Tags: r

My data is organised as follows: for each product, there is a tax rate for each year as well as a base year tax (baseyr).

```
product<-c("01","02","03","04")
baseyr <-c("10","8 GBP/tonne","8GBP/tonne + 8GBP/tonne","8")
yr1<-c("5","5 GBP/tonne","5GBP/tonne + 10GBP/tonne","5 + 5GBP/tonne")
yr2<-c("3","3GBP/tonne + 6GBP/tonne","3 GBP/tonne","3 + 5GBP/tonne")
yr3<-c("2","2","2GBP/tonne + 2GBP/tonne","excluded")

sched<-data.frame(product,baseyr,yr1,yr2,yr3)
```

For each year, I need to classify each product by tax type in a new column based on the following conditions:

```
#number -> only numbers in the tax
#nonnumber -> numbers and strings in the tax
#mixed -> either two strings or number and string; the two strings are specified by a plus sign 
#baseyr -> if the tax is "excluded" from the list, the tax to be used should be the value in base year, and the classification based on this
```

So if there are 3 years I need to generate 3 tax type columns. However the number of years changes randomly per dataset so I need to code with this in mind. My code is currently something like this:

```
yearnum<-3 #set number of years; it is between 1 and around 10 but there is no limit
schedule<-c(paste0("yr",1:yearnum)
tax<-c(paste0(schedule,"_tax")

for(i in 1:nrow(sched)){
#for each new tax type
for(j in tax){
#columns 3 to five where the yearly tax rates are 
for(yr in 3:5){
  #if the tax is excluded from the list, the base year tax should be used to determine the tax nature
  if(sched[i,yr] =="excluded"){sched[i,yr] <- sched[i,baseyr]}
  #if there is a plus sign it is a mixed tax
  if(grepl("\\+",sched[i,yr])){sched[i,j] <- "mixed"}
  #if it is not mixed but contains strings it is a nonnumber tax
  if(grepl("[:alpha:]",sched[i,yr])){sched[i,j] <- "nonnumber"}  
  #finally if it is neither of the above it must be a number tax  
if(is.na(sched[i,j])){sched[i,j] <- "number"} 
 }}}
```

NOTE: I do not know at the start how many years there will be in total; this has to be generated in the code. Any advice much appreciated, especially to avoid these for loops that don't seem to work properly for me.

The final output should be:

```
#so the output should be:
yr1_tax<-c("number","nonnumber","mixed","mixed")
yr2_tax<-c("number","mixed","nonnumber","mixed")
yr3_tax<-c("number","number","mixed","number")

#and the final dataframe:
sched<-data.frame(product,baseyr,yr1,yr2,yr3,yr1_tax,yr2_tax,yr3_tax)
```

Comment: in the future, use `dput` to produce the data example, as it will capture strings/factors or other behavior that might be present in your actual dataset.

Comment: For instance, the first line `product<-(` is missing a `c` in front of `(`.

Comment: Thanks, I will correct it, but I had to simplify the original code a lot since there was a lot of other elements and variables that are unnecessary to the issue that needs to be addressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `if_else` to change all the `excluded` into baseyr. Then use case when with regular expressions as shown below:

```
sched %>%
  mutate(
      across(starts_with('yr'), ~ifelse(.x == 'excluded', baseyr, .x),
             .names = '{.col}_tax'),
      across(ends_with('tax'),
             ~case_when(grepl("^\\d+$", .x) ~ 'number',
                        grepl('^[^+]$', .x)~'nonnumber',
                        grepl('[+]', .x)~'mixed')))



product                  baseyr                      yr1                     yr2                     yr3   yr1_tax   yr2_tax yr3_tax
1      01                      10                        5                       3                       2    number    number  number
2      02             8 GBP/tonne              5 GBP/tonne 3GBP/tonne + 6GBP/tonne                       2 nonnumber     mixed  number
3      03 8GBP/tonne + 8GBP/tonne 5GBP/tonne + 10GBP/tonne             3 GBP/tonne 2GBP/tonne + 2GBP/tonne     mixed nonnumber   mixed
4      04                       8           5 + 5GBP/tonne          3 + 5GBP/tonne                excluded     mixed     mixed  number
```

The regex is simplified in that I am checking for digits only (number), If there is `+` then mixed, then if no `+` then nonnumber.

Comment: Thanks! it works for what I need except the nonnumber. For instance if the tax is 8.20 GBP/100kg it is not classified as ```nonnumber``` but instead ```NA```. I'm not sure what this expression means: ```'^[^+]$'``` could you please explain further?

Comment: The other issue with "number" is if there are decimals like ```8.20``` instead of ```8``` then it also gets classified as ```nonnumber```. How could I correct this?

Comment: I think it works now with a couple of edits: ```~case_when(grepl('[0-9]+$', .x) ~ 'A', ``` and ```grepl('^[^+]*$', .x)~'S',```
                       
                        
                        )))```

Comment: @melange164 well i hope the answer did enough. Consider accepting it if it helped.

Comment: Yes, and thanks a lot! That was a complicated issue for me.